# Create separate assembly for each page in TFS Build 2012 defination

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am working on creating build from TFS 2012. I am able to generate build from TFS build templates but problem is that my website(ASPX pages), I am using after generating build is not creating separate dll for individual page.

But If I generate build from VS2012 I can generate build with separate assembly for individual pages.I can see this option when I click on publish and configure.

But how to have same option in Tfs Build templates ?? I have searched for MSbuild arguments and didn't find anything related to that

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for us was... change to Jenkins and use make.

But seriously -> you can watch what changes in csproj/sln. Then most of options in this file are switches in MsBuild.

Check:
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/05/how-to-auto-deploy-after-build-in-tfs.html
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment

Comment: thanks for links but I didn't find option for separate assembly for each aspx page

Answer (score 0):

The settings for "Create a separate assembly for each page and control" is saved in the publish profile with following format:

> ```
> <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
> <WDPMergeOption>CreateSeparateAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
> ```

So you can [create a publish profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx) with this setting and specify the publish profile in TFS Build Definition.